# Delete or hide compilation buffer when finished compile and run process

Tags: window, compilation-mode

Recently I'm using this function which is given bellow, to `compile` and `run` *C++* program. Everything works fine with this function.

I just want to delete pop-up window *(generated by this function)* after compilation and running procedure is finished.

[image]

And want the window to give me a message asking **:**

> press `<return>` key to delete current window and go-back.

I'm new to *Emacs* and have zero knowledge of *elisp*. So it would be very kind of you guys if you let me know how to done this work.

```
 (defun compile-and-run()
  (interactive)  
  (save-buffer)  
  (compile (concat "g++ " (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)) " -o " 
  (file-name-sans-extension (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name))) " && ./" 
  (file-name-sans-extension (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)))) t ) 
  (other-window 1)
 (goto-char (point-max))) 

(define-key c++-mode-map [f5] #'compile-and-run)
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: In the `*compilation*` buffer `q` is bound to `quit-window`, which by default will close the window and _bury_ the buffer. See the `quit-window` docs to see how to _kill_ the buffer

Comment: `quit-window` doesn't work on `*compilation*`, I think that's because I run the program in `*compilation*` buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `compile` mode actually exposes a *hook* that runs after compilation finishes, called `compilation-finish-functions`.  You can add your own hook to the compilation, and in that, just call the `quit-window` function that others have mentioned in the comments.

```elisp
(defun exit-after-compile-hook (cur-buffer msg)
  ;; nil: Don't kill the window.
  ;; 0: Affect visible and iconified frames.
  (quit-window nil (get-buffer-window cur-buffer 0)))

(add-hook 'compilation-finish-functions #'exit-after-compile-hook)
```

You can certainly combine these lines with a `lambda`.  You also may wish to *not* close the window in the event that compilation failed.  If you noticed, I passed `nil` to `quit-window`, which at least, keeps the buffer around.

Comment: great, I just add this `(when (y-or-n-p "Quit window? ")` before
`(quit-window nil (get-buffer-window cur-buffer 0))` so that I could hold that window open until I want to kill it. Is it good what i just added that way? And I wish, I could turn that y-or-n into in any key(**e.g. <return>**) this will close window on pressing the **<return>** key.

Comment: It does look like you could potentially wrap `y-or-n-p` (in a `let` expression) to remap the `y-or-no-p-map` key binding for return to invoke `y-or-n-p-insert-y`.  I haven't tried this, though.  For those mechanisms, check `subr.el`...